# Json http.get nodejs gives wrong data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Good day, I am trying to fetch a json file with http.get

```js
http.get("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197993482001"+
            "/inventory/json/730/2",function(res){
  var chunk2='';
  res.on('data',function(chunk){ chunk2+=chunk;
  });
  res.on('end',function(){
   console.log(chunk2);
  });
  
  });
```

But in my console there are only these 5 strange characters: �� (and some squares with numbers in it)

What is going on? Thank you

EDIT I tried adding res.setEncoding('utf8'); but it doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL in question returns a 302 (redirect) status code, so you should check `res.statusCode` and reissue the request using the provided `Location` header in the response (which points to the actual location). Alternatively, you could use the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module which will handle redirects for you.

As for the data you're getting: the server *does* return a content body for the 302 response, and that content consists of a 26 byte gzipped document that doesn't seem to contain anything:

```
$ curl --silent --no-location 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197993482001/inventory/json/730/2' | gunzip | wc -c
       0
```

Since Node interprets the response as UTF-8 (which it isn't), you get those strange characters.

Comment: plus1  = I visited link too, never even copped the redirect!